# SDK to unsubscribe from marketing emails in AWS Organizations member accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, aws-organizations

I have an AWS Organization and I create member accounts for every new project I make. Since I have control over all of the accounts I use the same email account for all of those, using the account-name+project-name@gmail.com pattern. 
This means that I get the same marketing email for every new account I create. I know I can unsubscribe manually, but since I create the member accounts through the CLI I was wondering if there is a way to automatically unsubscribe (or avoid being subscribed) through the SDK.

I've looked in the [AWS Organizations SDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/index.html#cli-aws-organizations), particularly around [create-account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/create-account.html) but haven't found anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

apparently there is no solution from AWS for this. The only place I found is [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/choose-email-preferences-aws/). Which involves manual intervention.

Doing this on Organization ID would be a good option.

meanwhile, I wrote this as a workaround.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
GET_URL = 'https://pages.awscloud.com/communication-preferences'
POST_URL = 'https://pages.awscloud.com/index.php/leadCapture/save2'
s = requests.Session()
def fetch(url, data=None):
    if data is None:
        return s.get(url).content
    return s.post(url, data=data).content
def get_form_id():
    forms = BeautifulSoup(fetch(GET_URL), 'html.parser').findAll('form')
    for form in forms:
        fields = form.findAll('input')
        for field in fields:
            if field.get('name') == 'formid':
                return field['value']
email_id = 'testing@example.com'
formid = get_form_id()
form_data = {'Email': email_id, 'Unsubscribed': 'yes', 'formid': formid, 'formVid': formid}
r = fetch(POST_URL, data=form_data)
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS recently changed this web form **again** breaking things for the existing unsubscribe function I had written.  They added 2 new required form data fields: `checksum` and `checksumFields`. The `checksum` field is a sha256 hash of a concatenation of all `checksumFields` values (single string joined with a `,`).

Below is my unsubscribe function written in python.
**NOTE:** I like @samtoddler's example using beautiful soup to dynamically lookup the formid vs hard-coding it in as a function input var like I have.

```py
def unsubscribe_aws_mkt_emails(email,
                               url='https://pages.awscloud.com/index.php/leadCapture/save2',
                               form_id=34006,
                               lp_id=127906,
                               sub_id=6,
                               munchkin_id='112-TZM-766'):
    '''
    Unsubscribes email from AWS marketing emails via HTTPS POST
    '''
    sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256()

    # Data fields used to calculate the payload SHA256 checksum value
    checksum_fields = [
        'FirstName',
        'LastName',
        'Email',
        'Company',
        'Phone',
        'Country',
        'preferenceCenterCategory',
        'preferenceCenterGettingStarted',
        'preferenceCenterOnlineInPersonEvents',
        'preferenceCenterMonthlyAWSNewsletter',
        'preferenceCenterTrainingandBestPracticeContent',
        'preferenceCenterProductandServiceAnnoucements',
        'preferenceCenterSurveys',
        'PreferenceCenter_AWS_Partner_Events_Co__c',
        'preferenceCenterOtherAWSCommunications',
        'PreferenceCenter_Language_Preference__c',
        'Title',
        'Job_Role__c',
        'Industry',
        'Level_of_AWS_Usage__c',
    ]

    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    }

    data_dict = {
        'Email': email,
        'preferenceCenterCategory': 'no',
        'preferenceCenterGettingStarted': 'no',
        'preferenceCenterOnlineInPersonEvents': 'no',
        'preferenceCenterMonthlyAWSNewsletter': 'no',
        'preferenceCenterTrainingandBestPracticeContent': 'no',
        'preferenceCenterProductandServiceAnnoucements': 'no',
        'preferenceCenterSurveys': 'no',
        'PreferenceCenter_AWS_Partner_Events_Co__c': 'no',
        'preferenceCenterOtherAWSCommunications': 'no',
        'Unsubscribed': 'yes',
        'UnsubscribedReason': 'I already get email from another account',
        'unsubscribedReasonOther': 'I already get email from another account',
        'zOPEmailValidationHygiene': 'validate',
        'formid': form_id,
        'formVid': form_id,
        'lpId': lp_id,
        'subId': sub_id,
        'munchkinId': munchkin_id,
        'lpurl': '//pages.awscloud.com/communication-preferences.html?cr={creative}&kw={keyword}',
        '_mkt_trk': f'id:{munchkin_id}&token:_mch-pages.awscloud.com-1644428507420-99548',
        '_mktoReferrer': 'https://pages.awscloud.com/communication-preferences',
        'checksumFields': ','.join(checksum_fields),
    }

    # calculated via js: f.checksum=v("sha256").update(s.join("|")).digest("hex")
    # src = https://pages.awscloud.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js
    sha256_hash.update('|'.join([data_dict.get(v, '') for v in checksum_fields]).encode())
    data_dict['checksum'] = sha256_hash.hexdigest()
    data = parse.urlencode(data_dict).encode()
    req = request.Request(url, data=data, headers=headers, method='POST')
    resp = request.urlopen(req)
```

Answer (score 0):

While I was looking into this problem, I stumbled across a different endpoint that was buried in the HTML of the unsubscribe page. It seems like it was once used for browsers with JavaScript disabled (although the page just redirects in that situation, so it's never actually used).

This endpoint works exactly the same way as it does in @samtoddler's answer, but the endpoint is https://pages.awscloud.com/index.php/leadCapture/save3. I've tested submitting a POST request to that endpoint with the following form data, and it seemed to work:

```
{
  "email": "test@gmail.com",
  "Unsubscribed": "yes",
  "formid": "34006",
  "formVid": "34006",
  "munchkinId": "112-TZM-766"
}
```

Wouldn't be a bad idea to use beautiful soup or something similar to get the form ID and Munchkin ID dynamically, but they haven't changed in 2 years so I feel fairly safe hard-coding them.